# I can't find any program I download

Tags: 10.04, files, installed-programs

I am new to Ubuntu and I am using version 10.04.

I download Frostwire with Firefox and installed it, but I can not find where the program is anywhere.

Comment: i pulled up 'places-home folder' then clicked an eyeglass and typed frostwire in it. can u send me a link to download ur updated version? i believe i have a very old version. i dnt think its even ubuntu 10.14

Comment: You can only upgrade it to Oneiric(Ubuntu 11.10) by following this link : http://www.howtoforge.com/how-to-upgrade-ubuntu-11.04-natty-narwhal-to-11.10-oneiric-ocelot-desktop-and-server

Comment: thank u all4 for the link. it helped an i got it everyone

Answer (score 1):

I just downloaded your frostfire abd found out it was not installing properly. I has dependacy error. to correct this in terminal type

```
sudo apt-get -f install
```

Answer (score 1):

This question was solved by the OP:

> I pulled up 'places-home folder' then clicked an eyeglass and typed
>   frostwire in it.

Answer (score 0):

[image]Check your 'Dash home' by clicking on the first icon of your launcher(top left corner of your screen) and type the name of what you downloaded in the search bar.Then double click on it to run it.

Comment: 'applications' is the only thing there where u said to click, there isn't a place to type anything.

Comment: Look a bit at the top.You would see a search bar - like the one you used to type in words in Google. Type the name of what you downloaded there.

Comment: no search bar even when i pull up another folder. no search bar only a eye glass

Comment: that picture isn't remotely close to what mine looks like

Comment: Did your Dash home looks like the image I posted above?

Comment: no it looks waay diff

Comment: Well, somewhere in your window manager it will tell you what version and type of window manager you are running.  Can you share that with us?

Comment: @djangofanHe has mentioned in the discription he is using 10.04 and not 11or12.
How can he have the unity interface??